# How to upgrade only single instance of webrole in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have created Azure project. Created one web role with two instances. I have published two instances from VS2010. Now i want to update another instance of the role with making the site down.Please help me with this asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although VIP swap is the preferred method (because rollbacks are easier), it can be done without using staging and production slots.

If you have more than one instance in a role, when you deploy the fabric controller will take care of everything for you. It will make sure that one instance is upgraded at a time.

If you look at the two instances on the instance tab for the cloud service, you will see that they are in separate update (and fault) domains. (Upgrade and update domains are the same thing - MS uses it interchangeably in docs, api, and portal). The fabric controller upgrades all the machines in one domain before starting on the other. In this case one instance will be upgraded, and only when it is successful, will the other one start to be upgraded. For more information look at [Overview of Updating a Windows Azure Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx#howanupgradeproceeds).

The short answer is that as long as you have more than one instance configured you should never worry about the site being down, either through upgrades or faults. Try this out with a simple project, and you will see that it works as expected.

Comment: you mean to say even i publish my cloud project always at least one instance is running. Then there no need to consider VIP swap and trying to update only one instance from cloud project. Helps lot Thanks Simon.

Comment: That's correct. As long as you have more than one instance running. Also try to match the instance count in your deploying config (from VS) to the number of instances configured in the portal - if by have fewer instances in your new service definition you might experience an outage as entire upgrade domains may be taken out.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update one instance.  That's why you have Production and Staging slots.  Upload your new code to the staging slot, check it out on the temporary URL from the dashboard.  Then, when happy, swap the VIP.  Finally, delete the old code that is now in the staging slot.

The load balancer actually handles moving users to the new instances after the VIP SWAP for an uninnterrupted user experience.